# How to write specs for this public method (using RSpec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have written the following class:

```
# This class is responsible for getting the data to create the sitemap
class City
  attr_accessor :country_version, :directory, :country_host, :locale

  def initialize(country_version, directory, country_host,locale)
    @country_version = country_version
    @directory = directory
    @country_host = country_host
    @locale = locale
  end

  def get_data
    ::City.find_each(:conditions => {:country_version_id => @country_version.id}) do |city|
      I18n.locale=(@locale)
      yield entry(city)
    end
  end

  private

  def entry(city)
    {
      :loc => ActionController::Integration::Session.new.url_for(
                  :controller => 'cities', 
                  :action => 'show', 
                  :city_name => city.name, 
                  :host => @country_host.value),
      :changefreq => 0.8,
      :priority => 'monthly',
      :lastmod => city.updated_at
    }
  end
end
```

I am using RSpec to write specs for this class. My specs so far cover the accessor methods and the constructor. I am lost however when it comes to the more complex method `get_data`. Can someone give me some hints how I can tackle the problem of writing a spec for that method?

Comment: This question would be better closed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @gikian He means that the question would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com, which is explicitly meant for questions of coding style/completeness.

Comment: @Dave Newton: From his last question (which he deleted and created this new duplicate) it seems that he doesn't want to know whether his specs are complete but how he can actually write specs for the `get_data` method.

Comment: @gikian Can you please add the versions of Ruby and Rspec (and probably Rails) you are using? That kind of information is almost always relevant, regardless of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test would surely be along the lines of:

- Does it blow up on instantiation?
- Does it return data when given good arguments?
- Does it return what I expect (zero/nil/exception?) when given bad arguments or those that lead to no results?

Some code:

```
describe :City do
  let(:country_version) { 123412 }
  # other useful args here
  context "On instantiation" do
    context "Given valid arguments" do
      subject { City.new country_version, ...}
      it { should_not be_nil }
      it { should be_a_kind_of City }
    end
  end
  end
  context "Given a country version id" do
    context "that is valid" do
      context "and records exist for in the datastore"
        let(:city) { City.new country_version, ...}
        subject { city.get_data }
        it { should_not be_nil } 
        it { should be_a_kind_of... (Array, Hash?) }
        it { should include( ...? }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously, this won't work as I've no idea what should be going in and out, but it gives you something to be going on with, and it implies some of the missing specs too (like invalid arguments and so forth)

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations for more.

Some of the comments here are right too, you probably will need mocks at some point, and you probably do need to refactor this method anyway, so posting to the code style forum might be an idea too.

Comment: @lain The spec you provided covers the whole class except the private method ?

Comment: @gikian No, it partially covers the public part of the class in certain aspects. It doesn't cover invalid arguments, or when the database has bad data etc etc. That's for you. As for testing private methods, see http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/034-issue-5-testing-antipatterns.html

Comment: @lain Can u please tell me about should be_a_kind_of and should include matchers? whats their purpose here ?

Comment: @lain one more thing. You used context for nested groups ... Is the 1st context is for the initialize method and the 2nd one is for get_data method? how can write wrong specs for my public methods... Thanks

Comment: be_a_kind_of checks the type of returned value is what you expect. Ruby is a dynamic language, you won't always get what you expect, so check... is it a Hash you expect, or an Array, or some other type of object? Should include examples are here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-7/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher, I'd use it against any kind of list/hash object. I'm infering that's what you're getting by the name `get_data`, but only you'd know.

Comment: @lain So if get_data returns an array I should write it { should be_a_kind_of (Array)} or I should mention the expected content of array ?

Comment: both - I usually have at least three lines for a successful return: check it's not nil, check it's the correct type, check it has the values I expected.

Comment: @lain if you look at the get_data method 
It returns the collection of records from database, So what I can check in the should be_a_kind_of 
and what it returns is of the form

City(id: integer, country_version_id: integer, name: string, label: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, jobs_count: integer, lat: float, lng: float)

Comment: @lain I am totally lost I am confused a lot... Can you please help me in writing a spec for my get_data method

Comment: gikian, you've been given at least 50% of the spec you need, along with links to the documentation and tips - what more can be given apart from the finished product that *you're* being paid for?

Comment: @lain I am a student and my exams are going on so I cant give time to these specs. I f you can do it I can pay you or if you know anyone else who can do it I am willing to pay for these specs. It will be a life saver for me 
Thanks and reply me..

Comment: If you couldn't give the time you shouldn't have taken on the job. It's a tough lesson, but project management skills are more important that coding skills in my view, as is taking responsibility for yourself. There are plenty of freelance sites out there to look for someone to do the work, but trying to get people on stackoverflow to do it for free by asking questions is *very* bad form.

Answer (score 0):

This is very verbose, your only actual method here is `get_data`. You could use:

```
class City < Struct(:country_version, :directory, :country_host, :locale)
  ...
end
```

To get accessors, constructors, and a bit more for free, and not test those (see [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html))

Comment: How can I write a correct spec for this class I am not getting any clear direction from any where I am searching from yesterday but no success :(